# How to implement ImageMap for states within country's map

Tags: html, css, image-processing

I need to implement India's map where on hover over the states eg. Delhi should highlight its Delhi's border and shows up a popup form.

I have no idea how to implement this.

Can anyone please guide me.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: If I remember correctly, you will need to pin out every single point and make your own boundaries. That will be time consuming if you don't have the points already, or get them from somewhere else, depends on how granular you want the borders to be. You might be better off using an existing map service, like google maps.

Comment: @scheien does google maps gives precise location of states, when I tried https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?csw=1 to find states, the results are overlapping with adjacent states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for an HTML [image map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map#Pure_HTML). Example borrowed from Wikipedia:

```
<img src="image.png" alt="Website map" usemap="#mapname" />
<map name="mapname">
  <area shape="rect" coords="9,372,66,397" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/" alt="Wikipedia" title="Wikipedia" >
</map>
```

You'll have to actually map the shapes in your map of India image to coordinates. There are some online tools that can help you do this. A quick google search found this one: https://www.image-maps.com/. Disclaimer: I haven't tried it myself. YMMV.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is there any way to highlight the borders of the hovered state also. Your solution helps me to get a rough area of the state, however I suppose I cant highlight the borders of the state

Comment: The `shape` attribute of the `<area>` tag supports more types than just `rect`. I believe you can use polygon shapes too which should allow you to get tight borders around the states in the image if you spend the time tracing over the borders. Use `<area shape="poly" ...>`.